# Adding A Button Between post-content and Related Posts Thumbnail Plugin on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a button to my WordPress template. Basically, I have the post and then there is the Related Posts Thumbnails widget that appears. I want the button to go between the text of the post and the related posts thumbnail widget. The code in my 'Single Post' that contains all of this is as follows:

```
<div class="post-content">
<?php the_content(__('<em><strong>More:</strong> Read the rest of this entry...</em>', 'life-is-simple')); ?>
</div>
```

I know the Related Posts Thumbnails plugin falls within this code because it's at that place when I 'Inspect Element' on Google Chrome. I can't find how to edit the order of things within that div though. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

### EDIT

Clarification: I am using the Life Is Simple WordPress theme although it has been custom editing quite a bit (mostly on the CSS side of things though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That plugin is probably appending the output to `the_content` with a filter .
That means , that the output is being added to `the_content` automatically. it is a common behaviour.

You need to look at the plugin´s admin interface to see if you can have an alternative way (I believe there is ) which is using a template tag. in that case, you should put the template tag after the div where the `the_content()` is .

**EDIT I :**

After a small dig, - in fact there is - you need to put

```
<?php get_related_posts_thumbnails(); ?>
```

Then the plugin should know by itself not to append to the_content.
For parameter passing, or if something is not working, go read their APi or help files.

Comment: I had looked into that previously but when I add <?php get_related_posts_thumbnails(); ?> it actually just adds three more related posts under the related posts that are already on there. It does the trick of displaying the related posts but doesn't get rid of the plugin editing the_content ...

Comment: you have to disable that in the plugin settings.

Comment: hehe : I am glad it worked for you, you could have saved 2 days by reading attentively the first answer :-) - it already said you should look at the admin interface options ... :-)

Comment: Yeah, the wording in the admin panel was a little confusing to me but I definitely should've read slower :)

Comment: I agree it is confused, when I have looked at the screenshot of the admin panel, I was also not so sure for 2 seconds what this option means (the first one ) . The plugin author should maybe change the description there.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to edit `single.php` or `archive.php` in your theme. If nothing is occuring there that looks familiar, it's probably using a loop. In which case you might find what you are looking for either in `loop.php`, `loop-single.php`, or `loop-archive.php` depending on what type of page you are on and how the theme was constructed. Add your button near where you find `Read the rest of this entry..`.

With more information (such as what theme you are using), one might be able to help more as well.

Comment: I just edited. I am using the Life Is Simple theme. I went into single.php (which is where it is being displayed) but like I mentioned, it doesn't show up in the code. It's somehow part of the_content but not visible in the actual coding of single.php ...